# CEF Sharp Blazor support

Tags: cefsharp

we currently using Microsoft WebView2 engine and thinking to migrating to another solution due to some Windows Explorer dependencies the engine has. I was wondering if CEF sharp has similar functionality offered by Microsofts BlazorWebView where basically the hosted Blazor application runs in the same process and does not require separate UI process.

Thanks!

Comment: Try https://github.com/jpmikkers/Baksteen.Blazor.CefSharp

Comment: Looks like it could do the job, thanks!